# Set StyleSheet with Font size for elements in QTreeWidget

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I try to set new font size for header and content of a tree widget.

Problem here is: I can not set font size directly for the content because at the moment I set, the content does not appear yet. So I can just set StyleSheet, so when content appears, it follows the StyleSheet. This is my code:

```
    int modifier = 2;
    /* Set font size for headers */
    QFont f = ui.treeWidget->headerItem()->font(0);
    if (f.pointSize() == 10)
        f.setPointSize(f.pointSize() - 1);
    else
        f.setPointSize(f.pointSize() - modifier);
    ui.treeWidget->headerItem()->setFont(0, f);
    ui.treeWidget->headerItem()->setFont(1, f);
    ui.treeWidget->headerItem()->setFont(2, f);

    /* Set font size for content */
    ui.treeWidget->setStyleSheet("{font-size: " + QString::number(f.pointSize()) + "}");
```

This is the result, the header font size is changed but the content is not. Where was I wrong, or do you have any other solutions for that?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
ui->treeWidget->setStyleSheet("QTreeWidget { font-size: " + QString::number(f.pointSize()) + "pt; }");
```

Note my addition of both `QTreeWidget` and `pt;`.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically you can adjust the content in `QTreeWidget::item` stylesheet subcontrol, but Qt ignored font-size in this case and I don't know why.

Alternatively you can adjust font size of content area in next way:

```
ui.treeWidget->setFont(f);
```

Comment: thanks for your idea. But this way does not work. I tried this way before already. Because the moment we set font, there is nothing as content of tree widget, so this code has no effect. Therefore, I must use setStyleSheet

Comment: How you added the content? It works fine for newly added content in my case (I use `addTopLevelItem` method after `setFont` call.

Comment: I also use `addTopLevelItem`. No matter where I put method `setFont` (before or after `addTopLevelItem`), it still does not work. :(